# Generic method gives error

Tags: c#, generics

I have tried to write a generic method for the below mentioned code snippet.But it gives error on the `OrderBy` clause ? Could you tell me why ?

```
var cache = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StateListDto>>(cache.StringGet(AppConsts.States));
if (values != null) return new ListResultOutput<StateListDto>(values.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList());
```

***Generic method :***

```
 public ListResultOutput<T> GetCache<T>(string cacheKey)
   {
      var cache = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
      var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(cache.StringGet(cacheKey));
      return values != null ? new ListResultOutput<T>(values.ToList().OrderBy(o=>o.Name)) : null;
   }
```

***call :***

```
var values = GetCache<StateListDto>(AppConsts.States);
```

***StateListDto.cs***

```
 public class StateListDto 
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

***It gives this error:*** (click to see the full size image)

[image]

Comment: The "generic" code cannot guarantee that `T` has a `Name` property.  You _could_ add a `where T : StateListDto` constraint, but it's not clear if that's _correct_.

Comment: @DStanley How can I sort out this issue then ? Any advice ?

Comment: In what way is this generic? What types are supposed to be supported?

Comment: Your code is not generic as-is.  Do you expect the method to execute for _any_ `T`?  What if `T` does not have a `Name` property?

Comment: @Amit lot of types.all are custom `dtos`. like `CityListDto`,'ShowListDto' and more.But all are having `Name` property.

Comment: Anyway, the correct solution is to **remove** the last line, return `values` directly. It's not the responsibility of `GetCache` to do sorting.

Comment: There are many ways to solve it - derive all types from a base class or interface that has a `Name` property; take the sorting out of this method, let the caller pass in a sorting expression, or use `dynamic` (last resort)

Comment: @Amit Then where I do that sorting ? I need to use this on the drop down and I don't like to change any existing code on the angular or html side.It's having 50+ drop downs.

Comment: Use whatever tool you have to refactor your code. There's no *good* reason for a fetching function to care about sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the way you want to order by as a parameter like this:

```
public ListResultOutput<T> GetCache<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T,object> selector)
{
    var cache = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
    var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(cache.StringGet(cacheKey));
    return values != null ? new ListResultOutput<T>(values.OrderBy(selector).ToList()) : null;
}
```

***call :***

```
GetCache<StateListDto>("yourKey", i=>i.Name);
```

In this way you don't force your class to implement anything - and you can choose to order by other parameter in your code

Comment: can you tell me how to call this method ?

Comment: GetCache<StateListDto>("yourKey", i=>i.Name);

Comment: Thanks a lot.This is what I need.Perfect solution for my scenario. No need to do any existing code change.Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting to use this for more than just `StateListDto` I would suggest creating an interface or base class that does have the property called `Name` then you can guarantee it exists.

Something like:

```
public interface IDto
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

and then you can change your method to:

```
public ListResultOutput<T> GetCache<T>(string cacheKey) where T: IDto
{
    var cache = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
    var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(cache.StringGet(cacheKey));
    return values != null ? new ListResultOutput<T>(values.ToList().OrderBy(o=>o.Name)) : null;
}
```

Comment: do I need to implement this `interface` on all of my `dtos` ?

Comment: @Sampath You will on all the `dtos` that you wish to use this method with. If you don't need it on all then perhaps a better name for the interface like `INamed` as per Davids answer

Answer (score 1):

> But all are having Name property.

Then create a common interface for them, something like this:

```
public interface INamed
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

And all your models with that property can implement that interface:

```
public class StateListDto : INamed
```

Then you can use that interface as a type constraint on the generic method:

```
public ListResultOutput<T> GetCache<T>(string cacheKey) where T: INamed
```

That way the compiler can guarantee that the type of `T` will have a `Name` property.

Note that a base class, concrete or abstract, can also be used to accomplish this.  Though personally I prefer to use interfaces over inheritance unless there's a specific reason to use inheritance.